# Fast conversion of Bitmap to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, bitmap, imagesource

I'm programming in WPF(c#) for image processing purpose. What is fastet way for converting `Bitmap` to `ImageSource`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try converting it to a BitmapImage first:

```
public BitmapImage ConvertBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {         
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();

        return image;
    }
```

Then:

```
public void MyMethod(System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitmap)
{
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.Source = ConvertBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

You didn't explain where the Bitmap was coming from so I had to leave that part out.